# Subtracting pointer from an integer

Tags: c++, pointers, subtraction, pointer-arithmetic

```
    int *p = new int; 
    int a = 10; 
    cout << a+p;
    cout << a-p;
```

Printing a+p, p+a, p-a gives an address, but a-p gives me an error. Why is this so? Aren't pointer addresses integers? And if so, shouldn't a-p give me a negative value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of pointer arithmetic, pointers aren't equivalent of "integer representing some address". Even addition isn't that simple:

- You can't add pointer to pointer
- Writing `p+1` doesn't mean "get address value from p variable and increase it by one". Actual address increment amount depends on size of pointed variable, so incrementing `int64_t *p` will give different result from incrementing `int8_t *p`

Why do we have such "strange behavior" for addition and subtraction of pointers? Simple answer: because it's defined that way in C++ standard:

> 5.7 Additive operators
>
> For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic or unscoped enumeration type, or one operand shall be a
>   pointer to a completely-defined object type and the other shall have
>   integral or unscoped enumeration type.
>
> For subtraction, one of the following shall hold:
>
> — both operands have arithmetic or unscoped enumeration type; or
>
> — both operands are pointers to cv-qualified or cv-unqualified versions of the same completely-defined object type; or
>
> — the left operand is a pointer to a completely-defined object type and the right operand has integral or unscoped enumeration type.

But there's a reason behind that restriction (which is actually describe on the same page of standard). Pointer arithmetic is intended for the following usage: if `p` points to some element in array, `p+1` points to the next element, `p-1` points to the previous and `p1-p2` shows number of elements between p1 and p2. In these terms `p1+p2` doesn't make any sense, the same for `1-p`, so they are treated as syntax errors.